# How to resolve fixed position elements jumps when scrolling | React JS, framer-motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have a scenario where the container changes its position from fixed to relative, during scrolling. I have used framer-motion to give a smooth effect during position transitioning. framer-motion is a great library to handle these scenarios, however my code is not working as expected in all browsers. When I scroll to the offset where the position changes from fixed to relative, it jumps and sits in the place, where as am expecting it should be smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add "layout" prop to the component you are animating.
You can read more about it in the [docs](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/component#layout-animation)